# Vertically centering a plus sign inside of a circle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically and horizontally center the plus sign inside of the circle. I've tried using `line-height`, but that does not seem to work:

**CODE**

```css
.circle {
  font-size: 3.27rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 94px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  line-height: 94px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  height: 94px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(94, 94, 94, 0.68);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fcce00;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  span {
    line-height: 94px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>+</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks perfectly centered to me mate.

Comment: 37 on top and 30 on bottom is definitely not perfectly vertically centred.

Answer (score 5):

Although you code seems to work as you desire (tested in FF),  you need to take your `span` out of `.circle` in your CSS, because this is not a pre-processor CSS, therefore not valid CSS.

#### Snippet:

```css
.circle {
  font-size: 3.27rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 94px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  line-height: 94px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  height: 94px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(94, 94, 94, 0.68);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fcce00;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}
span {
  line-height: 94px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>+</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plus sign is actually vertically centred correctly as far as fonts are concerned. The bottom of the plus symbol aligns with the box baseline - what you don't see however is the top line. If you change the plus symbol to a capital letter, such as B, you will see what I mean.

Check this article for an in-depth explanation: http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the practical behavior of concerned css properties to achieve vertical align of minus sign and plus sign inside button(including circles) upon increasing the font-size(to any extent) regardless of font-family used.

**Use Case:** Sometimes you want bigger buttons with a plus or minus sign inside it. But the font-size is too small for the button. As you increase the font-size of the button, the plus and minus sign fails to align vertically as was the case with me. That's when I came up with the following solution.

**Note:** I could't find a solution anywhere else, so I ended up with this solution. I am open to any say you have on the solution so feel free to leave some comments:)

```css
/* common style */
button {
   height: 50px;
   width: 200px;
   background: #216AFF;
   color: white;
}

.minus {
  font-size: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.plus {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<button class="minus">-</button>
<br>
<button class="plus">+</button>
```

Use display-flex on the button and use the value of line-height to position the plus or minus sign vertically within the button. Increase in line-height value moves the signs downward and and decrease in line-height value moves the signs upward. Thanks!